# My camera does not move correctly through 3d space

Tags: javascript, camera, raytracing

I have created a raytracing algorithm which currently displays a triangle on screen, and am now having trouble moving the camera around correctly.

I would like my code to have the arrow keys rotate the camera, and WASD move the camera in 3D space. The camera currently rotates correctly using two rotation matrices for y and z rotations.

## The Problem

Moving the camera, rather than rotating, is where the issue arises. To move the camera, I require two vectors - cameraForward and cameraRight. These vectors can be added on to the position of the camera when input is detected. These vectors will also need to change when the cemara is rotated, in the same rotation as all the rays experience. But when I apply these rotation matrices to the vectors representing cameraRight and cameraForward, there seems to be an issue. Holding down the A or D key will result in the camera moving unexpectedly in circles or odd wavy lines.

I managed to fix the issue with cameraForward by using a different method. I added a couple lines of code which calculate when the ray at the centre as been 'fired' and proceed to set cameraForward to that ray. Therefore cameraForward will always follow the central ray being sent out i.e. the centre of the field of view. However, I cannot do the same with cameraRight, as this vector is not in the field of view.
Before solving cameraForward using this method the same issue arose with moving forwards and backwards.
I also tried taking the cross product of one of the other rays along with the cameraForward vector which I thought might produce cameraRight, but to no avail - more sporadic camera movement
I do not have the vector for cameraUp either so cannot calculate the cross product to find cameraRight.

I also thought maybe the code was being run too many times and the vector was rotated multiple times. However mvoing the code elsewhere had no effect and the method it was already in is run every frame, so I do not believe that is the issue.

Here is my code to rotate the camera right and the method which does the rotation.
camRight's inital value is (0, 0, 1)

```
camRight = normalize(rotateVector(camRight, rotationZ));
camRight = normalize(rotateVector(camRight, rotationY));

function rotateVector(v, m) {
    return new Vector3(dot(m.a, v), dot(m.b, v), dot(m.c, v));
}
```

I know this code works as the code rotating the camera view functions correctly using the same matrices and methods.
(the following code)

```
myDirection = normalize(rotateVector(myDirection, rotationZ));
myDirection = normalize(rotateVector(myDirection, rotationY));
```

When the user presses A or D the following code is run

```
    if (keys[65]) {
        camPos = add(camPos, normalize(camRight));
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
    if (keys[68]) {
        camPos = subtract(camPos, normalize(camRight));
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
```

The camera moves forwards and backward correctly, as previously mentioned. Initially, the camera moves left and right correctly too (as its inital value of (0, 0, 1) is correct), but if I rotate the camera, the values for cameraRight go wild.

Have I assumed something wrongly? or is there a flaw in my logic somewhere?

Thank for any help

Comment: I probably don't understand your specific issue, but I do know that when you perform rotations, you have to take into consideration the point of rotation, which might explain the apparent circular motion.  Ie, let's say you move the camera to (2,0,1).  If you perform a rotation, it might assume the rotation is around the origin (0,0,0), hence leading to the circular motion.  To correct, typically you first "move" the object to the origin, rotate, and then reverse the "move" to leave the object back at its original coordinates...

Comment: By the way, after further reflection, my prior comment also explains the "camera moving unexpectedly in circles or odd wavy lines".  Eg, if the camera is at (2,2,0) and is rotated about the Y axis via the origin (0,0,0), at 90 deg it will find itself at (0,0,~-2.8), at 180 deg it will find itself at (-2,-2,0) and at 360 back to (2,2,0).  So the camera will appear to be spinning in a sinusoidal fashion relative to the Y axis...